# setState of a selectInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The problem that I am facing that when I add the setState on the child component, the validation and going to the next step doesn't work because it is handled on the handleChange function on the parent component.

So, How can I from handleChange on the parent component setState of a SelectInput that it exists on the child component?

```html
    getStepContent(stepIndex) {
        switch (stepIndex) {
            case 0:
                return (<CInfo ci={this.props.cInfo} errors={this.state.errors} onChange={this.handleChange}  />);
             
            case 1:
                return
```

```html
    handleChange = (event) => { 
       
        const { stepIndex } = this.state; 
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;
       
        var type = null;
        switch(stepIndex) {
            case 0: type='UPDATE_CINFO'; break;
            case 1: type='UPDATE_PINFO'; break;
            default: break;
        }
        this.props.dispatch(updateCurrentForm( type, { [name]: value } ));

        this.setState( this.state , () =>  this.validateFields()  )
       
    }
```

please, any advice will be appreciated

Comment: I want to mature sure that I understand the question... My understanding is the following: (1) there is an onChange event in the child. (2) the hadleChange function is in the parent. (3) you want this function to set a state in the child. It's that right?

Comment: exactly and it works for all the textInput but not for the selectInput

Comment: I see. Sorry, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is very unclear question but I'm gonna try it. I assume your handleChange function is in your parent component which updating state and your input is in your grand child component CInfo where you want to trigger handleChange function on onChange. If so change your code like this

```
<CInfo ci={this.props.cInfo} errors={this.state.errors} onChange={props.change}  />);
```

and in your parent connect it like this where you call your child

```
change={this.handleChange}
```

Comment: thank you first for your answer. The handleChange function is triggered for all the textinput but not for the selectinput and that it's my problem